# How to structure GIT repositories for development and testing?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, git

We have been using GIT with Visual Studio 2008 for the last 2 years and are happy with the functionality it provides us. We have gone live with the new system today and from next week we need to start implementing new functionality for v2.0 of the system however we don't want people to pick up those changes as soon as they log in until v2.0 is finished.

I have heard of branches but never used them myself and I believe they will provide us with the functionality we need.

So my question is: what is the best way to structure our repositories so that we can develop v2.0 without affecting the live system?

We currently only have one repository and one branch and there are two developers in the company. I guess we will need a new branch called "Development" or something similar for v2.0, and the existing branch will be used for bug fixing of the current system.

Any advice and tips will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Using GIT for 2 years, "You have heard of branches but never used them yourself"?

Comment: Reason for that is I am the "junior" dev in the company. If I knew the answer I woulnd't bother asking would I?

Comment: here's a fun way of learning to visualise the git branching process: http://pcottle.github.com/learnGitBranching/. Also, I'm sure there are many other great resources out there.

Comment: Sure :) But branching and merging is such a fundamental feature in git ... Anyways, I suggest that you start with http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: @w0lf thank you. Are you saying that branches will offer the functionality that we need?

Comment: @Andreas thank you. I am sorry if I sound like a noob but I never really touched the more advanced features of git and that's my fault I admit. I shall have a read and see what suits us best

Comment: @OopsieDaisie No problem - actually, it is a good question ("How to structure GIT for development and testing") - there are different models for that, for example you could check out http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: @OopsieDaisie yes, see Andreas's link above

Comment: Thank you guys. Would anybody like to merge the information above into an answer so that I can select it as the correct answer to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branch :
git checkout -b branchname

git commit -am "ur changes"

Merging:
git  checkout branchname

git merge mergingbranchname

You can create local branch in your client also

For details check out this  [link](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)